# how to prove that two iterated integral are different

Tags: measure-theory, iterated-integrals

We have the following function: $$f(x,y)=
    \begin{cases}
    1, & 0 \leq x-y \leq 1\\
    -1, & 0 \leq y-x \leq 1 \\
0, & \text{other cases}
    \end{cases} $$
and I need to prove that $$\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{\infty} f(x,y) dx dy \not = \int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty} f(x,y) dydx $$
I have defined the following sets:

$D_1=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2:  0 \leq x-y \leq 1 \}=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: x \leq y \leq 1+x \}$
$D_2=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2:  0 \leq y-x \leq 1 \}=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: x \geq y \geq x-1 \}$.

So we have that $$f(x,y)=
    \begin{cases}
    1, & (x,y) \in D_1\\
    -1, & (x,y) \in D_2 \\
0, & \text{other cases}
    \end{cases} $$
I have done the following:
$A=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: x,y \geq 0\}$
$$\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{\infty} f(x,y) dy dx=\int\int_{D_1 \cap A} f(x,y) dy dx + \int\int_{D_2 \cap A} f(x,y) dy dx=\int_0^{\infty}\int_y^{y+1}-1 dxdy+\int_0^{\infty}\int_{y-1}^{y}1 dxdy=$$ $$= \int_0^{\infty}-y+y+1 dy+\int_0^{\infty}y-1-ydy=0$$
$$\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{\infty} f(x,y) dx dy =\int\int_{D_1 \cap A} f(x,y) dx dy + \int\int_{D_2 \cap A} f(x,y) dx dy= \int_0^{\infty}\int_{x}^{x-1}1 dydx+\int_0^{\infty}\int_{x+1}^{x}-1 dxdy=0$$
I don't know what's wrong.. I would be really thankful if you helped me \
Thank you

Comment: In this context, you shouldn't be splitting up the region of integration at all—the point of the exercise is to show that the value depends upon the order of integration. In the first case, you're asked to literally evaluate $\int_0^\infty f(x,y)\,dy$ as a function of $x$, and then integrate that function over $x$; in the second case, you should evaluate $\int_0^\infty f(x,y)\,dx$ as a function of $y$, and then integrate that function over $y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Splitting into two areas where $f(x,y)=+1$ or $-1$ will not work, as they are both infinite in extent, leaving you with $\infty - \infty$, which is not defined.

Instead, doing the first integral first:
$$\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{\infty} f(x,y) dx dy \\= \int_0^{1}\int_0^{\infty} f(x,y) dx dy + \int_1^{\infty}\int_0^{\infty} f(x,y) dx dy \\= \int_0^{1}\left(\int_0^{y} f(x,y) dx +\int_y^{y+1} f(x,y) dx\right) dy \\+ \int_1^{\infty}\left(\int_{y-1}^{y} f(x,y) dx +\int_y^{y+1} f(x,y) dx\right) dy \\ = \int_0^{1}\left(-y+1\right) dy + \int_1^{\infty}0\, dy \\= \frac12$$

The second integral will be similar but end up with $\int\limits_0^{1}\left(x-1\right) dx + \int\limits_1^{\infty}0 \,dx = -\dfrac12$, showing that the order of integration matters. The cause is concealed in the integration of $0$ over an infinite range.